# Installing X pack on elasticsearch, logstash and kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-x-pack

I am new to elasticsearch, logstash and kibana .
I am using Windows

i recently install x-pack plugin by folowing this tutorial :
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/x-pack/5.1/installing-xpack.html

the main point is :

Go to ES_PATH
elasticsearch-plugin install x-pack

Go to Kibana PATH
kibana-plugin install x-pack

everything goes well, until i try to verify my x-pack instalation.
i go to kibana url. http://localhost:5601/
if everything is right, based on documentation, i should be prompted to login to kibana.

but, all i got is this message:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask